# How do you add images to a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a user control with right click..add..user control..

I want to add images to the resources of the control. Double clicking resx changing the dropdown menu from strings to images, and clicking "add resource".

the message suggests that the control doesn't have its own resources, but I find that strange 'cos if that is the case then why does it have its own resx file?

So, how do I add images to the resources of the user control?

Should I ignore the message?

[image]

Comment: That is not where you have to add the resources! Try using the Resources file under compositecontrol1/Properties

Comment: @IgorMesaros isn't that the same file?

Comment: No, the one I'm talking about is the project resource file, where as the one you are trying to modify is the resource file for you class which is auto generated.

Comment: @IgorMesaros so now i'm wondering then what controls, if any, have their own resource file?   (and that one would add to,  more local than the project resource file)

Comment: I can't really say what is the need to make a usercontrol have its own resources. What I find more useful, is a custom controls project which houses more then one control, and contains all the shared resources for those controls.

Comment: @IgorMesaros  i've imported a project before via a dll, but would that dll include images? And also, if only one control needs to be used, then importing the project just for the one control, would be overkill becaue there are many more images than one needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113966/discussion-between-barlop-and-igor-mesaros).

Comment: The chat contents seems to have been deleted.. I think what I decided was to just let the project have the resources

Answer (score 0):

You can add ressources directly to the .resx of your user control if you think it belongs there. In this case simply ignore this warning. You just have to keep in mind that this file is automatically generated/populated. So don't change any properties if you don't know their meaning.

**Edit:** I think the warning has following meaning

- On the one hand when you change resource properties this can affect the optic and behavoiour of your the control (up to corruption).
- On the other hand: When changing the control out of the designer, resource properties get set automatically and your previously edits of the resource file can be overwritten.

Comment: the file is "automatically generated" from what? suppose I add stuff to the resources of it.. where would it autogenerate from?

Comment: when you create a user control and add something to it, VS will create this file and store information there (e.g labeltext, positions,...)

Comment: Why am I getting that warning though?  Is there a more correct way to bring up the window to add resources to the user control?

Comment: I think it means: On the one hand when you change resource properties this can affect the optic and behavoiour of your the control (up to corruption). On the other hand: When changing the control out of the designer, resource properties get set automatically and your previously edits of the resource file can be overwritten.